# ASP.NET Web Application - Menu DropDown (Site.Master)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to do dropdown menu in my project.
This is the code:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark navbar-custom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <img src="Imgaes/TrustnetLogo.png" />
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" title="Toggle navigation" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                        <li><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#" runat="server">Option 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" runat="server">Option 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" runat="server">Option 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the result:

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygaPj.png)
But when I click on it nothing happen.

I expecting that menu will open after I press Products.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please elaborate why exactly you are expecting that menu will open after I press Products

Comment: Were you able to link bootstrap and jquery cdn in your code?

Comment: Yes '<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>'

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it:

If your Bootstrap version is `v5.1`, you can add the following css and js file to your project `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

And  try to change your  `data-toggle="dropdown"` into `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`

You can read [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/) to know more.

**Update: a demo**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            @*<img src="Imgaes/TrustnetLogo.png" />*@
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" title="Toggle navigation" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                <li><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" runat="server">Option 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" runat="server">Option 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" runat="server">Option 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Already tried this. Still not working.

Comment: @Bar Halifa ,Have a look at my update.